# Get id php and insert value in textarea

Tags: php

I have textarea. When i click submit, value of textarea is inserting in db. Then i have a button. With click on button i went to go to the page that saved this value of texarea. And the link will be like site.com/index.php?id=1. And at this page will show your saved value of textarea

```html
<?php
include 'db.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Php practice</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 $textareaValue = trim($_POST['content']);
 
 $sql = "insert into textarea_value (textarea_content) values ('".$textareaValue."')";
 $rs = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 $affectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($conn);
 
 if($affectedRows == 1)
 {
  $successMsg = "Record has been saved successfully";
 }
}
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
 
<label>Textarea:</label>
<div>
    <textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="content" required><?php  
    $_GET['textareaValue'];
    ?></textarea>
</div>
 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
$giv = "SELECT `id` FROM `textarea_value` WHERE `textarea_content` = '$textareaValue'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $giv); 
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$id = $row['id'];

?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  echo $id;
} else {
  echo "failed";
}
?>
<a href="index.php?id=<?php $id; ?>">Go</a>


 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: __Question__, do you have it?

Answer (score 0):

IF this is where your question is about:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="content" required><?php  
$_GET['textareaValue'];
?></textarea>"
```

just:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="60" name="content" required>
<?php  
   echo /*<<<here*/ $_GET['textareaValue'];
?>
</textarea>
```

IF it's not what you're looking for, just try to be clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to insert a PHP variable from a DB, then you can try

```
<textarea name = "profile_skills" id="summery-desc" rows='10' cols='40' 
maxlength='350' placeholder="My Experience, Skills, & Interests..." form = 
"submitForm" ><?PHP echo ($skills ?? '');?></textarea>
```

This works for me.